# Can't add nice shading to highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have two lines, `A` and `B` and I try to paint in different colors area between them: green where `A > B` and red where `A < B`. I've implemented shading area via `arearange` series type. You can see my work here: http://jsfiddle.net/kSNsT/

The problem is: when data grouping occurs (i.e. single point in chart corresponds to more than one day in my case), shading goes crazy. If you narrow down chart interval with range selector in the bottom, shading is almost perfect. But when you widen it up it goes out of line bounds.

I tried to write my own handler for `arearange.dataGrouping.approximation` but it didn't help really much. Any ideas?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982924/javascript-charting-library-to-handle-shading-area-between-two-lines) but the solution won't work with grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Sebastian Bochan** states in his answer it's much simpler if you just create the extra areas for the over / under shading directly from the data -- I don't think you really need to do the work you're doing to build your shaded areas. *However* that does't solve your data grouping problem.

I can get close -- but not quite perfect. At first I thought that the issue was just using the same aggregate function on all the data sets, but that doesn't work as it goes wrong whenever it aggregates over a crossing point.

What I did was create two sets of range data that go from A to B:

```
for (i = 0; i < data1.length; i ++) { 
    var valA = data1[i][1];
    var valB = data2[i][2];       
    under[i] = [data1[i][0], valA, valB ];  
    over[i] = [data1[i][0], valB, valA ];  
}
```

Then I gave each set of range data it's only aggregate function that changes the shape of the graph to only show the over/under as applicable.

```
function shadeApproxUnder(low,high) {
    low = average_(low);
    high = average_(high);
    if (low > high) return [ high, high ];
    return [ low, high ];
}

function shadeApproxOver(low,high) {
    low = average_(low);
    high = average_(high);
    if (low > high) return [ low, low ];
    return [ low, high ];        
}
```

and also one for the lines so that I know the aggregate values are the same:

```
function lineApprox(values) { 
    var avg = average_(values);
    return avg;
}
```

That gets close as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/khF8n/), but you can see that it doesn't work perfectly. That's because there are points where the two lines cross where there's no data-point. Since I assume the system is drawing things in chunks between the two data points there's no way to get that to work.

You can try returning `[ null, null ]` instead of `[ high, high ]` or `[ low, low ]` in the aggregate functions and see more clearly the gaps.

It looks like you really need to somehow get the datapoints added at the crossover junctions, and I'm not sure how to do that. You can't just edit the data because the data grouping will change it -- but you can't do it in the aggregate function as you can't add datapoints.

You could attempt to save all the aggregate data point values generated when you draw the lines, and use that to insert the area graph with the extra data points extrapolated -- but I'm not clear on how that'll work when you refresh the graph (I suspect it will not).

**EDIT**

I had a bash at a better solution, but it still doesn't work -- maybe you or someone else can spot the flaw.

Basically, as I said above, we want to add datapoints for the line intersections on our shading curve, this is my attempt at that -- done using the data from the chart stored in 'dataGrouping' which is the data *after* it's grouped:

```
function updateChart(chart, refresh) {
    var dir = 0;
    var over = Array(), under = Array();
    var dataA = chart.series[2].groupedData;
    var dataB = chart.series[3].groupedData;

    j = 0; // Index into over/under
    for (i=0;i < dataA.length; i++) {            
        if (dataA[i].y < dataB[i].y) {                           
            if (dir == -1) { 
                over[j] = under[j] = getIntersection(dataA[i-1], dataA[i], 
                                                     dataB[i-i], dataB[i]);         
                j++;
            }
            dir = 1;
            over[j] = [ dataA[i].x, dataA[i].y, dataB[i].y ];
            under[j] = [ dataA[i].x, dataB[i].y, dataB[i].y ];
        } else if (dataA[i].y == dataB[i].y) { 
            dir = 0;
            over[j] = [ dataA[i].x, dataA[i].y, dataA[i].y ];
            under[j] = [ dataA[i].x, dataA[i].y, dataA[i].y ];
        } else { 
            if (dir == 1) { 
            over[j] = under[j] = getIntersection(dataA[i-1], dataA[i], 
                                                 dataB[i-i], dataB[i]);             
                j++;
            }
            dir = -1;
            over[j] = [ dataA[i].x, dataB[i].y, dataB[i].y ];
            under[j] = [ dataA[i].x, dataB[i].y, dataA[i].y ];
        }    
        j++;
    }
    chart.series[0].setData(over, refresh);
    chart.series[1].setData(under, refresh);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/p7usV/).

**NOTE** Sometimes this seems to get stuck in a loop, I'm not sure why.

You can see the line intersect function in the fiddle, it's lifted from Wikipedia. There are two problems with this, first there's no sensible event to attach this function to -- in the fiddle it's attached to `load` and `redraw`. But you can't start a redraw from inside the `redraw` event (which makes sense) so the shading shown will always be one set of data behind the plot lines -- this is obvious if you switch the zoom settings for example. But, it should be reasonably easy to fix that if you're prepared to edit the Highchart source code and put a hook in that will allow you to attach the update function after the grouping but before final rendering.

Why is the shading still not right? Either I've got the line-intersection logic wrong, or it's to do with accuracy when working with very small (accurate) numbers and very big ones. Or it's just a high chart limitation.

The other option, which is probably not going to look right is to use the `redraw` and the `Renderer` class and just directly draw the shaded areas as an SVG path onto the graph.

If I come up with anything else I'll edit again -- but I think I'm out of ideas for how to do this.

**EDIT 2**

OK, I *think* the 'correct' way to do this is probably to modify Highcharts itself and create a new chart type with it's own renderer (so it'd be an extended area chart that knew to change colors on the cross-over and draw the lines in different colors). I've no idea how easy that is.

However, the hack to draw the SVG paths directly over the graph actually works OK and we already have all the logic from the other examples on this page, so an update chart function might look like:

```
var over_path = null;
var under_path = null;
function updateChart(chart) {

    // Create the paths on the first call ...
    if (!over_path) {
        over_path = chart.renderer.path();
        over_path.attr({fill: '#bbeebb'}).add();
    }
    if (!under_path) {        
        under_path = chart.renderer.path();
        under_path.attr({fill: '#eebbbb'}).add();     
    }

    // Get the data from the chart
    aPts = chart.series[0].points;
    bPts = chart.series[1].points;

    var i; 
    var overPts = Array();    // SVG path instructions
    var underPts = Array();   
    var mX = chart.plotLeft;  // Offset for each point
    var mY = chart.plotTop;
    var iPt;                  // For the intersection points

    // Draw the path along line B, than back along A/B 
    // to complete a closed space. First go along B

    overPts[0] = underPts[0] = 'M'; // Move to start
    overPts[1] = underPts[1] = bPts[0].plotX + mX;
    overPts[2] = underPts[2] = bPts[0].plotY + mY;
    overPts[3] = underPts[3] = 'L'; // Draw from here
    for (i=1; i<aPts.length; i++) { 
        overPts[overPts.length] = underPts[underPts.length] = bPts[i].plotX + mX;
        overPts[overPts.length] = underPts[underPts.length] = bPts[i].plotY + mY;
    }

    // Now go backwards along A looking for the cross-overs ...    
    var dir = 0;    
    var newDir = 0;
    for (i=(aPts.length - 1); i>=0; i--) { 
        var A = aPts[i].plotY + mY;
        var B = bPts[i].plotY + mY;

        newDir = (A>B)?1:((A<B)?-1:0);
        if (dir && (dir != newDir)) {
            // Change direction, add intersect point
            iPt = getIntersection(aPts[i], aPts[i+1], bPts[i], bPts[i+1]);
            overPts[overPts.length] = underPts[underPts.length] =iPt.plotX + mX;
            overPts[overPts.length] = underPts[underPts.length] = iPt.plotY + mY

        }
        dir = newDir;

        // Add matching data point 
        overPts[overPts.length] = aPts[i].plotX + mX;
        underPts[underPts.length] = aPts[i].plotX + mX;
        if (A > B) { 
            overPts[overPts.length] = B;
            underPts[underPts.length] = A;
        } else { 
            overPts[overPts.length] = A;
            underPts[underPts.length] = B;
        }        
    }        

    // Update new path
    over_path.attr({'d': overPts});
    under_path.attr({'d': underPts});

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/Twdft/)

*Note:* Here I'm reading undocumented contents of the chart object to work out where the points are, since this isn't in the official API they may always change in future versions of Highcharts (although, they probably will not -- but it's good to be aware of the possibility).

The main problem is the area appears before the initial graph draw animation, but you can probably find a way round that (you could fade it in the first time which might look cool). Since further redraws aren't animated it's not a problem. There's also some 'fuzziness' in some views which I think is due to anti-aliasing, so you might want to tweak that.

Unless there's a different chart package that does data grouping that can take account of line intersections I think that the above is probably the best solution that doesn't involve delving into the source of a charting package.

Anyway, thanks for the interesting problem to occupy my mind this week. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot SpaceDog for your work! I really like your first solution, so much more precise than mine! And I'll take a look at your second try. If it comes to rewriting SVG related code, I'd actually prefer to use another chart library, if there are any others with data grouping.

Comment: I actually improved your first solution by using same `shadeApprox` for both `arearange` series. Now only upper shading exceeds its bounds: http://jsfiddle.net/khF8n/3/

Comment: I'm afraid the bottom one is still writing over the bounds -- you just can't see it because it's covered by the top one (because the mid-points are the same if you use the same approx function). Set `visible: false` on the `over` series and you'll see it. I've been thinking and I really can't see how to do it without getting datapoints onto the B line at the cross-over points -- the area graph is always going to be polygons with corners at the data points -- as long as there's a datapoint on each side of the cross-over then you'll always see this. Maybe rewrite the HighStock data grouper?

Comment: Great thanks for another edit. I hope it will help other HighStock users. (Rather modest) bounty well deserved!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two line series, you can use four, two lines and two shadows (`arearange`) like in the example http://jsfiddle.net/tRpMQ/5/

Comment: That's exactly what I did: added two `arearange` series. The problem is that this way doesn't work well with data grouping and I don't see anything helpful in API, except `arearange.dataGrouping.approximation` and I didn't have much success with that.

Comment: Please update my example with your data, in other words add all points in my structure, becuase its diferent than yours.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see how your example may actually help me at all. I need shading not in sense of displaying a shadow of single line, but in sense of filling/painting area between two lines.

Comment: But what is wrong with my example? I introduced you how to fill area between series, by arearange.