# Highcharts - areaRange with different fill colors depending on which line is higher

Tags: highcharts

I have essentially the same problem described in:
[JavaScript charting library to handle shading area between two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982924/javascript-charting-library-to-handle-shading-area-between-two-lines)

That is to say: color the area between two lines, with the fill color of each portion of the area determined by which of the two boundary lines is higher at that point.

The question referenced above was answered, but the question is two years old and the solution  is a little convoluted. Have subsequent advances in Highcharts introduced better / cleaner ways of solving this particular problem?

Comment: The related charts with up-to-date references: http://jsfiddle.net/mKABN/359/ and http://jsfiddle.net/q95kK/81/

Comment: I had a similar requirement and this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2me4Z/11/) helped me to achieve this. I've made some configurations to this and it worked like a charm

Comment: I've updated the fiddle for more clarification http://jsfiddle.net/k94vuaw3/.